# How can the trivial representation not be in some $R\otimes R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, tensor-products

Where do I foul up?

In (e.g.) $SU(3)=A_2$ the tensor product $(1,0)\otimes (1,0)=(2,0)+(0,1)$. No $(0,0)$.
But on the other hand still $(1,0)\otimes (0,0)=(1,0)$. This immediately begs
the question

1. what happened to Schur's lemma and
2. imagine some 6j symbol $(ABC|DEF)$ where $A=B=(1,0)$, $C=(0,0)$. Is $ABC$ no admissible triangle and the 6j vanishes?

My only idea is that the Dynkin diagram is symmetric and you first
must symmetrize/antisymmetrize over the reps to get the correct ones,
i.e. the proper irreps in this case would be $((1,0)+(0,1))/V2$ and 
$((1,0)-(0,1))/V2$. (And what does this do to the dimensions? Same as 
$(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, I think.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation, but in general there's no reason that, for a representation $V$, $V \otimes V$ will contain a copy of the trivial representation. (It is true that $V \otimes V^{\vee} \simeq V \otimes \overline{V}$ will, though.)

Comment: I don't think your question is comprehensible. Could you at least cite Schur's lemma and explain why it has any bearing on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial representation lies in the tensor product of two irreducible representations $A\otimes B$ if and only if $B$ is the dual representation to $A$. For this group, $R$ is not self-dual, so we would expect the trivial to appear in $(1,0)\otimes (0,1)$, and it does: $(1,0)\otimes (0,1)=(1,1)\oplus (0,0)$.

Comment: In ten years I learnt infinitesimally more on Lie algebras :-), so I understand this now. Could you also answer me the following on notation: "Real" and "Complex" for irreps means the same as "self-dual" and "not self-dual"? The arrow in the familiar HOMFLYPT skein diagram implies the irrep may be complex, while "no arrow" (e.g. Kauffman) only works with real irreps?

Comment: @HaukeReddmann I only answered it because someone else seemed to find it important! I hoped you hadn't been waiting for the answer all this time... Real representations are always self-dual. For 'complex' representations one must be a bit more careful, and check that they are not real but in disguise.

Comment: Now THAT was a helpful warning :-) (Always overgeneralizing, I infer "real/complex" is more a label of the Lie algebra, and you mean things like, say, (1,1) of A2.)